# How to modify this RegEx expression so it matches any characters followed by an @ (just one)

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a RegEx expression so it matches an email. I created that one:

```
.+@{1}[a-z]{3,}.{1}(\bcom\b|\bes\b)
```

Conditions:

- Any character followed by just ONE @
- The email domain lenght must have at least 3 characters followed by a point
- The TLD of the domain must be exclusively ".com" or ".es"

The issue here is that when I try to input for example, "example@@gmail.com" it matches.
It just have to match "example@gmail.com" with just one @

Comment: Try changing `.+@` to `[^@]+@` since the `@` symbol is matched by `.`

Comment: Use a negated character class `[^\s@]+@[^\s@]{3,}\.(?:com|es)\b` https://regex101.com/r/RQmwOs/1 or use `[a-z]{3,}` instead of `[^\s@]{3,}`

Comment: @Thefourthbird That should be an answer; it's what I was going to post

Comment: @Richiban You can post it if you want.